# How to have copies of a NFT with different metadata under the same contract

Tags: erc-721, nft

I want to mint different copies of a NFT, for the copy with id 0 has the metadata A and the one with the id 1 has the metadata B, and so on, I want these minted copies to be part of the same NFT contract.

Is there a way to do so? All the tutorials I've been reading only show how to mint copies of a single kind of NFT, with its metadata set at contract creation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the base URI that is often set at contract creation. Your metadata is a json file that contains information about the nft e.g. its name, description, image url. The token URI is the link that points towards this metadata json file, sometimes made by concatenating the baseURI with the token ids. So, to have a different metadata for each token id you will need a different json file and a different token URI.